# Remove %20 from generated tel: links

Tags: javascript

I'm using an saas crm system that allows click 2 dial function.

Crm generates tel: links as following: https://office.crm.com/_module/crm/view/account_view/tel:+373%20699%2066%20299

The only link format which is working with the softphone is: https://office.crm.com/_module/crm/view/account_view/tel:+37369966299

Following question. Is it possible with a code injector chrome/firefox extension to automatically remove the %20 value from all links that contain "tel:"?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m confused, those aren’t `tel` links, those are `http` links that have “tel” in them. Ignoring the space, are they supposed to include all of that?

Comment: Yes. Sorry those are http links. All I want to achieve is to force browser to delete those %20 from links.

Comment: Where do the number come from? Why are there spaces in them? The best solution would be not to have the spaces in them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you:

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll('a[href]')
    .forEach(
        (link) => {
            if(link.href.includes('tel:')) {
                link.href = link.href.replace(/%20/g, '');
            }
        }
    )
;
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/k0pjv65m/1/

It is pretty straightforward, grab all links with an href, if it includes the tel: string, remove any url-encoded spaces.

Comment: I would just add that this feels like patching the problem, and I’d recommend making the field itself not contain or allow spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Unfortunately, I can't make any changes to the crm, since it is a saas tool. I'm asking myself why would they add spaces, because in other modules of their software, there are no spaces in the links, and click 2 call woks perfectly.

Comment: That worked! The only thing i had to do is to replace %20 with a white space in your code! Many many thanks!